# Ember save form in ajax call

Tags: ajax, ember.js

I have my edit form with all of my information load in it, and when I click on the save button, it take all of field to save even if there is nothing changed in it..

I wanted to get back in an object only the index and their value that I modified in the form.
I have stricly no idea how I can do this with Ember.

Here is my code :

```
App.EnquiryUpdateController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
id: null,
isSaved: false,

actions: {
    save: function() {
        var enquiry = this.get('model');
        console.log(enquiry);
        var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(enquiry));
        obj = this.cleanObject(obj);
        $.ajax({
            url: host + 'mdf/enquiry/' + enquiry.id,
            type: 'POST',
            accepts: 'application/json',
            data: obj
        });
        this.transitionToRoute('enquiry', enquiry)
    }
},
});
```

My Route:

```
App.EnquiryUpdateRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.modelFor('enquiry');
    }
});
```

And my Template :

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="enquiry/update">

    <div class="enquiry-update">
        {{#if isSaved}}
        <div class="saved">Enquiry updated successfully</div>
        {{/if}}
        <div>
            <label>Customer Name</label>
            {{input value=customerName}}
        </div>

        <div>
            <label>Customer Email</label>
            {{input value=customerEmail}}
        </div>

        <div>
            <label>Customer Phone</label>
            {{input value=customerPhone}}
        </div>
        <div>
            <button {{action "save"}}>Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

If I update the customerName, I only want to have it in my object { customerName: "toto" } instead of all of them..

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Well, the concept you're going to want to implement will be dirty attribute checking.  This means you'll need to keep a copy of the original data and then either mark an attribute as dirty, or compare attributes and only send the different attributes.

Comment: You mean keeping the original data with Ember-Data and to compare them with the new one ? Damn, I thought about it but yeah its gonna be awful to do..
Do you know any other way to do it ? (cleaner)

Comment: Are you using Ember Data?

Comment: Not to save the enquiry from my server, I only use it for now to save the user who's log. (info such as name, account name etc..)